# Checkpointing and restarting X11 applications

Tags: c, x11, restart, function-interposition, blcr

I want to checkpoint and restart X11 applications.  I am using the BLCR (Berkeley Lab Checkpoint/Restart (BLCR)) tool.

BLCR is not able (without modifications) to reinitiate the connection to the X-Server.  I used an interposition library to log all Xlib function calls with their parameters to a text file.

Now I want to be able to re-use this logged function call.
Is there a better way than to save them to a text file and parsing/interpreting them during the restart procedure?

The application which is checkpointed should redo the calls which were logged, but this seems to be not as easy as it has sounded first.

Comment: I think the approaches used by http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zandy/guievict/ or http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra make more sense than your approach.  What do you think?

Comment: Good question, but a hard problem.

Comment: I don't follow, why redo the calls?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested this, but I think you might be able to solve this one by spawning an `xmove` child process and making sure this gets stored in the checkpoints. Your application would talk to xmove instead of the XServer directly and every time you restore from checkpoint you would "move" to the current xserver again.